# Is there Export All Features in View Extent equivalent with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, symbology

I would like to dynamically classify a layer's symbology based on the current view extent. As in, quantities of a specified field will be classified into quantiles based on the range of values of the visible features. Since the symbology tab does not appear to support this out of the box, I need to instead limit the layer's values to those within the visible extent. I know ArcMap supports exporting data to those features limited to the view extent.

Is this possible with ArcPy?

Comment: I think exporting all features in the view extent is no problem using ArcPy.  However,  dynamically classifying symbology is where you may come unstuck.  I think you should focus this question on solving just that first part, and start by including a code snippet of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142890/can-the-maximum-and-minimum-values-of-raster-display-be-changed-automatically-wh/143070#143070

Comment: @FelixIP - Thanks, but that question was specifically for raster. The first answer would have been useful, but `Clip_analysis` does not support coordinates as clipping bounds, unlike it's raster-based equivalent, `Clip_management`. Looks like I would have to create a vector to clip to in order to go that route.

Comment: Virtual polygon geometry will do. After this you can do clip into in_memory, or just select by location and re-compute min-max for selected values

Comment: Ok, didn't know about in_memory - that's cool. Yes, select by location or clip are both options. To be honest, I have no idea what you mean by virtual polygon geometry. Can you clarify?

Comment: I've not seen it called that but the term seems to be being used for a geometry object which is being created in the answer code by `polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this script, it clips all the layers in mxd using clipping polygon or optional dataframe extent

##""********************************************************************************************************************

```
import arcpy, sys, os
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
# Argument 1 is the list of Rasters to be converted
clipFeatures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inRasters = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
# The list is split by semicolons ";"
inLayers = inRasters.split(";")
##anOutPutFolder="C:/urs-data/Aerials/from_MXD/"
anOutPutFolder=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)+ os.sep
##arcpy.AddMessage(inLayers)
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

try:
    def isLayerExist(mxd,lName):
            layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
            for l in layers:
                if l.name in lName:
                    return l
            raise NameError,'\n%s layer not found. Exiting..\n'%lName
    if len(clipFeatures)==0:
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        ext=df.extent
        array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(ext.XMin,ext.YMin),
                     arcpy.Point(ext.XMin,ext.YMax),
                     arcpy.Point(ext.XMax,ext.YMax),
                     arcpy.Point(ext.XMax,ext.YMin),
                     arcpy.Point(ext.XMin,ext.YMin)])
        polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)
        clipFeatures=polygon
        anExtent=ext
    else:
        d=arcpy.Describe(clipFeatures)
        anExtent=d.extent
    envelope='%f %f %f %f' %(anExtent.XMin, anExtent.YMin, anExtent.XMax, anExtent.YMax,)
    m=anOutPutFolder.find('.gdb')+anOutPutFolder.find('.mdb')
    for inL in inLayers:
        inRaster=isLayerExist(mxd,inL)
        desc = arcpy.Describe(inRaster)
        arcpy.AddMessage(inRaster)
        thePath=desc.catalogPath
        theArray=thePath.split("\\")
        n=len(theArray)-1
        theFile=theArray[n]
        theFile=theFile.replace('.shp','')
        theType=desc.datasetType
        if theType=='RasterDataset':
            arcpy.Clip_management (inRaster, envelope,anOutPutFolder+os.sep+theFile )
        else:
            if m==-2:
                theFile=theFile +".shp"
            outFile=anOutPutFolder+os.sep+theFile
            arcpy.Clip_analysis(thePath, clipFeatures, outFile, "")
            result=arcpy.GetCount_management(outFile)
            nFeatures=int(float(result.getOutput(0)))
            if nFeatures==0:
                arcpy.Delete_management(outFile)
        arcpy.AddMessage ("...processed")
except NameError, theMessage:
    arcpy.AddMessage (theMessage)
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Something wrong")
```

You'll see clearly what virtual polygon is. It is just a geometry..

Comment: Sweet! That did the trick! Thanks man. The symbology portion should be a bit more straight forward - I believe I'll need `ApplySymbologyFromLayer` and `symbology.classBreakValues` for the final portion of creating a dynamic symbology. @PolyGeo - I'll do my best to add the completed code once this is all done. Thank you for your help @FelixIP!

Comment: Glad it works. Correct classBreakValues is the only thing to recalc